# Hotmail inbox deleted after setting up evolution

Tags: 12.10, thunderbird, email, evolution

I recently set up my hotmail account on evolution. I have been using thunderbird but just to see how is evolution I did so. But now when I log in to http://hotmail.com, all my emails in my inbox have disappeared/deleted. But I could see all those emails in evolution and thunderbird. How do I get those emails back to Hotmail website. I suppose some settings are messed up in evolution?

Comment: You probably set any of the clients(maybe even hotmail) to the setting:Delete when loaded from the server.
Nothing much to do I guess.

Comment: Hurray!All the email were in the deleted folder in the web interface. Thanks Aditya & Dr_Bunsen

Comment: @BGovind Nice that your problem is solved. Can you mark Aditya's answer as the right one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would find that all your mails are transferred in POP folder in your Hotmail Account. Look for it in your Trash Folder in Web Interface of Hotmail. You should also take a backup of profile folder of Thunderbird as a precaution.